# Do the methods in Apache's FileUtils peform synchronous (blocking) i/o?

Tags: synchronous, java-io, fileutils

Do the methods in Apache's FileUtils perform synchronous (blocking) i/o?

I am making a call to FileUtils.*copyDirectoryToDirectory*. In my next line, I want to delete the directory that I copied.

Example:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(source, destination);
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(source);
```

Just want to make sure this is "safe" and asynchronous (non-blocking) i/o isn't happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is not part of the standard JDK, it a class in the [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/io).
2. The operations you mentioned do ***not*** use non-blocking IO.

So to answer your question, yes, your overall operation is safe.

Comment: Thanks so much. The reason I asked is because we are sometimes getting this error after the second line is excecuted: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory <directory>. Not sure why yet.

Comment: That should read: Unable to delete directory <source>. Not a very helpful message. We're thinking it may be due to file(s) inside the directory being locked. The files/directories are stored on a Mac OS X system. After we upgraded the OS from 10.4 to 10.6, our users occasionally get this error when they use our system to try and delete. At this point, we're not sure how to debug this, since we're not able to duplicate the issue on our local systems.

Comment: You might try putting a slight delay between copying and deleting, in the case that file handles are still open at the OS level. Also, do you have a guarantee that the user will not have any files in the `source` directory opened in another program?

Comment: No guarantees, no. We actually don't care if the files are open - the content is static (served up by Apache). If we could somehow force delete, that would be great, but there doesn't seem to be a way using FileUtils.

Comment: You may want to try using `FileUtils.forceDelete`, it makes a more concerted effort to remove files and directories. It will also return you a useable error if it could not delete the directory for any reason.

Comment: Would `FileUtils.forceDelete(source)` still fail if there is a lock on a file inside the directory? I also considered using `FileUtils.move(source)`, then later deleting, but wasn't sure if moving would be handled the same way if a file lock existed.

Comment: Since file locks (and permissions) are an OS level semantic its impossible to force deletion of files with a pure Java solution. The same applied for moving the directory.

Comment: I'm going to try the `FileUtils.move(source)` into a backup directory and later delete...by later, I mean the next time the user attempts a delete, I will wipe out the backup directory on the next delete. Hopefully file locks will not be an issue with the move. Thanks for your help, Perception. I'll report back if we don't hear anything from our users in awhile :).